# Is there any way to define a current DateTime as a default value for Date in @RequestBody of get method

Tags: spring-boot

here is my model class for the request body

```
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
@Data
public class ActiveAccountRequest {
    @Column(name = "startDate")
    @DateTimeFormat(pattern="yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss")
    @JsonFormat(pattern = "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss")
    private LocalDateTime startDate;
    @Column(name = "endDate")
    @DateTimeFormat(pattern="yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss")
    @JsonFormat(pattern = "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss")
    private LocalDateTime endDate;
    private List<Character> channel;
}
```

My Repository user for JPA connection

```
@Repository
public interface ReportingGenRepo extends JpaRepository<ReportingGeneral, Integer> {

    @Query(value = "SELECT REPORTING_GENERAL.USERNAME AS userName, " +
            "ANY_VALUE (REPORTING_GENERAL.CONTACT_NUMBER ) AS contactNumber,ANY_VALUE (REPORTING_GENERAL.PRIMARY_KEY) AS primaryKey," +
            "MIN( REQUEST_TIME ) AS minRequestTime ,MAX( REQUEST_TIME ) AS maxRequestTime, " +
            "COUNT(IF ( RESPONSE_CODE = '1', 1, NULL )) AS success,COUNT(IF " +
            "( RESPONSE_CODE != '1', 1, NULL )) AS failed,COUNT(*) AS totalHits,CHANNEL as channel" +
            " FROM REPORTING_GENERAL WHERE " +
            " REPORTING_GENERAL.ID > 0 AND CHANNEL IN ?3 AND (REPORTING_GENERAL.REQUEST_TIME  BETWEEN ?1 AND ?2)" +
            "GROUP BY channel, username",
            countQuery = "SELECT count(*) FROM REPORTING_GENERAL WHERE " +
                    " REPORTING_GENERAL.ID > 0 AND CHANNEL IN ?3 AND (REPORTING_GENERAL.REQUEST_TIME  BETWEEN ?1 AND ?2)" +
                    "GROUP BY channel, username ", nativeQuery = true)
    public Page<ActiveAccountReport> getActiveAccountReportFilters(
            LocalDateTime startDate,
            LocalDateTime endDate,
            List<String> channel,
            Pageable pageable);
```

Here is my Controller class

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/repo")
public class ReportingGenController {
    @Autowired
    private ReportingGenService reportingGenService;

    @GetMapping("/get")
    public Page<ActiveAccountReport> findAll(@RequestBody ActiveAccountRequest activeAccountRequest,
                                   @RequestParam(value = "page",defaultValue = "0") Integer page, @RequestParam(value = "size",defaultValue = "1") Integer size){
        return reportingGenService.paginatedActiveAccountReports(activeAccountRequest,page,size);

    }
}
```

Now I want to give a default value for my endDate and startDate in the requestBody.Can anyone help me please.

Answer (score 0):

Just initialize the fields with desired default `LocalDateTime`.

Comment: can you please explain a little bit, where an how I should initialize it?

Comment: @Imran For example, in class `ActiveAccountRequest` set `startDate = LocalDateTime.now()`.

Comment: please upvote to my question so that I can get reputation to accept answers of others

Comment: when I upvote someone's answer or question it says `Thanks for the feedback! You need at least 15 reputation to cast a vote, but your feedback has been recorded.

`

Comment: I am getting wrong filter results by implementing your method, `startDate = LocalDateTime.now()` , can you please help me little bit, I can provide you my whole code, thank you

Comment: @Imran It's a different problem, open a different question.

Comment: here it is. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75045908/filter-in-pagination-using-spring-boot-doesnt-work-properly can you help please

Answer (score 0):

When using Lombok especially `@Data` annotation you cant set a default value,

In my opinion, you have 2 choices to set the default data for your variable,

The first one: delete `@Data` annotation from your class and implement the getter and setter manual and set your value, like the following snippet

```
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
public class ActiveAccountRequest {
    @Column(name = "startDate")
    @DateTimeFormat(pattern="yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss")
    @JsonFormat(pattern = "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss")
    private LocalDateTime startDate = LocalDateTime.now();
    @Column(name = "endDate")
    @DateTimeFormat(pattern="yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss")
    @JsonFormat(pattern = "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss")
    private LocalDateTime endDate = LocalDateTime.now();
    private List<Character> channel;

//getter and setter
}
```

For the second one you can use inner class builder to implement it, look at this reference https://www.baeldung.com/lombok-builder-default-value

Comment: which second one you are talking about

Comment: @Imran inner class builder to implement it, look at this reference https://www.baeldung.com/lombok-builder-default-value

Comment: Sorry it didn't work, when I set the startDate and endDate in the setter methods it returns empty content as , `{
    "content": [ ],
    "pageable": {
        "sort": {
            "empty": true,
            "sorted": false,
            "unsorted": true
        },
        "offset": 0,
        "pageNumber": 0,
        "pageSize": 4,
        "unpaged": false,
        "paged": true
    },
    "totalElements": 0,
    "totalPages": 0,
    "last": true,
    "size": 4,
    "number": 0,
   ,
    "numberOfElements": 0,
    "first": true,
    "empty": true
}`